# React Tutorial giving TypeError

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I decided to learn React and started with the official tutorial. All is good until I get to this state of my code. The problem seems to be about property squares of current in the render function of Game component which is defined but I'm not sure why it's flagged as an error

```
    function Square(props){
  return ( 
    <button className = "square" onClick = {() => props.onClick()}>
      {props.value}
    </button>  
  );
}

class Board extends React.Component {
  renderSquare(i) {
    return <Square value = {this.props.squares[i]} onClick = {() => this.props.onClick(i)} />;
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div className="board-row">
          {this.renderSquare(0)}
          {this.renderSquare(1)}
          {this.renderSquare(2)}
        </div>
        <div className="board-row">
          {this.renderSquare(3)}
          {this.renderSquare(4)}
          {this.renderSquare(5)}
        </div>
        <div className="board-row">
          {this.renderSquare(6)}
          {this.renderSquare(7)}
          {this.renderSquare(8)}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class Game extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      history : [{
        squares : Array(9).fill(null)  
      }],
      xIsNext : true
    };
  }
  handleClick(i){
    const history = this.state.history.slice(0, this.state.stepNumber);
    const current = history[this.state.stepNumber];
    const squares = current.squares.slice();
    if(calculateWinner(squares) || squares[i]) {
      return;
    }
    squares[i] = this.state.xIsNext ? 'X' : 'O';
    this.setState({
      history : history.concat([{
        squares : squares
      }]),
      xIsNext : !this.state.xIsNext,
      stepNumber : 0,
    });
  }
  jumpTo(step){
    this.setState({
      stepNumber : step,
      xIsNext : (step % 2) ? false : true,
    });
  }
  render() {
    const history = this.state.history;
    const current = history[this.state.stepNumber];
    const winner = calculateWinner(current.squares);
    let status;
    if(winner) {
      status = 'Winner : ' + winner;
    }
    else {
      status = 'Next Player : ' + (this.state.xIsNext ? 'X' : 'O');
    }
    const moves = history.map((step, move) => {
      const desc = move ? 'Move #' + move : 'Game start';
      return (
        <li key = {move}>
          <a href="#" onClick={() => this.jumpTo(move)}>{desc}</a>
        </li>
      );
    });

    return (
      <div className="game">
        <div className="game-board">
          <Board 
            squares = {current.squares}
            onClick = {(i) => this.handleClick(i)}
          />
        </div>
        <div className="game-info">
          <div>{status}</div>
          <ol>{moves}</ol>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

// ========================================

ReactDOM.render(
  <Game />,
  document.getElementById('container')
);

function calculateWinner(squares) {
  const lines = [
    [0, 1, 2],
    [3, 4, 5],
    [6, 7, 8],
    [0, 3, 6],
    [1, 4, 7],
    [2, 5, 8],
    [0, 4, 8],
    [2, 4, 6],
  ];
  for (let i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
    const [a, b, c] = lines[i];
    if (squares[a] && squares[a] === squares[b] && squares[a] === squares[c]) {
      return squares[a];
    }
  }
  return null;
}
```

And this is the error I get

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'squares' of undefined
    at Game.render (pen.js:208:41)
    at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper._renderValidatedComponentWithoutOwnerOrContext (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.14.7/react-with-addons.js:6336:34)
    at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper._renderValidatedComponent (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.14.7/react-with-addons.js:6356:32)
    at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper.wrapper [as _renderValidatedComponent] (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.14.7/react-with-addons.js:12879:21)
    at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper.mountComponent (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.14.7/react-with-addons.js:5969:30)
    at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper.wrapper [as mountComponent] (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.14.7/react-with-addons.js:12879:21)
    at Object.mountComponent (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.14.7/react-with-addons.js:13613:35)
    at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper.mountComponent (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.14.7/react-with-addons.js:5974:34)
    at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper.wrapper [as mountComponent] (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.14.7/react-with-addons.js:12879:21)
    at Object.mountComponent (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.14.7/react-with-addons.js:13613:35)
```

Comment: Did you try to add `stepNumber : 0` to the `state` inside the `constructor` of the `Game` component ?

Comment: @DavidDomain Silly me

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So in your Game render function you start with these three lines of code

```
const history = this.state.history;
const current = history[this.state.stepNumber];
const winner = calculateWinner(current.squares);
```

However, in your Game constructor function, you do not set stepNumber in the state:

```
constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
        history : [{
            squares : Array(9).fill(null)  
        }],
        xIsNext : true
    };
}
```

Therefore, when you do

`const current = history[this.state.stepNumber]`

what you are essentially doing is

`const current = history[undefined]`

which means when you do

`const winner = calculateWinner(current.squares)`

you are actually doing

`const winner = calculateWinner(undefined.squares)`

and there is your problem. You need to set stepNumber in your state in the constructor function.

Comment: Is there a way I can use a debugger along with the tutorial to figure out these errors since understanding the errors thrown seem to be hard?